# Can't access array inside object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, electron, svelte

I'm passing an object to a svelte component (from the Electron main process) and while it shows up perfectly in the console, I cannot access the array inside it. However, when I copy the object from the console (or using `JSON.stringify(testObject)`) and use it directly (-> `copiedObject`), it works:

```html
   <script>
    let testObject = {};
    window.electronAPI.testDataM2R((m2rData) => {
        testObject = m2rData;
        console.log("testObject:", testObject);
    });

    let copiedObject = {
        filename: "testResults.csv",
        readRows: 3,
        invalidRows: 0,
        finishedReading: true,
        data: [
            {
                tcName: "",
                tcSuccess: true,
                tcFunctions: [],
            },
            {
                tcName: "TestClass",
                tcSuccess: false,
                tcFunctions: [
                    {
                        tfName: "testBasics",
                        tfSuccess: true,
                        tfEntries: [
                            {
                                teSuccess: true,
                                teLine: "6",
                                teAssertType: "ASSERT_EQUAL",
                                teComment: "1 == 1",
                            },
                        ],
                    },
                    {
                        tfName: "basicTest",
                        tfSuccess: false,
                        tfEntries: [
                            {
                                teSuccess: false,
                                teLine: "145",
                                teAssertType: "ASSERT_EQUAL",
                                teComment: "0.25 == p.getTest()",
                            },
                        ],
                    },
                ],
            },
        ],
    };
</script>
   
<p>{JSON.stringify(testObject)}</p> <!-- this output is exactly the same as the line below -->
<p>{JSON.stringify(copiedObject)}</p>   <!-- this output is exactly the same as the line above -->
<p>{testObject.filename}</p> <!-- this works -->
<p>{copiedObject.filename}</p>  <!-- this works -->
<p>{testObject.data[1].tcFunctions[0].tfName}</p>   <!-- this DOES NOT work -->
<p>{copiedObject.data[1].tcFunctions[0].tfName}</p> <!-- this works -->
```

So the last two lines are the important bit - why does `testObject.data[1].tcFunctions[0].tfName` give me:

> *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '1')*

While this `copiedObject.data[1].tcFunctions[0].tfName` does, which is just the output from `{JSON.stringify(testObject)}`?

Obviously, I need to be able to iterate through the object arrays in order to display all the elements, so I would really appreciate some help on this!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: looks like async at work? see: [How to return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: I don't think so - then the other lines accessing `testObject` should also fail, shouldn't they? I have also tested it using a more elaborate component where the data is loaded `onMount` - with the same result.

Comment: You say you're passing it from the Electron `main` process. If this is relevant to the question, you should show some related code - or otherwise remove the _electron_ tag from the question.

Comment: @Slbox: The `window.mlvAPI.testDataM2R...` is the Electron code. And to be honest, I'm not sure if it's relevant, but it is the only difference between the objects, isn't it?

Comment: Are you absolutely positive both objects are identical? Your error implies that accessing index 1 (i.e. the second object) on `data` is invalid, so that's where you'd look for a difference.

Comment: Your object doesn't contain anything that cannot be sent via [structured clone](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Structured_clone_algorithm), right?

Comment: @ThomasHennes: Yes, the output from the two `JSON.stringify()` is **absolutely** identical.

Comment: @Slbox: No, the object is as you see above - `strings`, `numbers`, `boolean` and `arrays`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is happening is that initially `testObject` is just `{}`, this means that `{testObject.data[1].tcFunctions[0].tfName}` will give you an error because it is trying to read the first element of an array that does not exist, hence the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '1')`

Why does it work however for the two other options ?

`JSON.stringify(testObject)` will initially print `{}`
`testObject.filename` will initially print `undefined`

No errors there!

After your electron function ran, `testObject` will be filled with properties and reactivity kicks in, the markup is updated where necessary.

Technically it first says`undefined` and then `testResults.csv` but this happens so **extremely fast** that you do not notice.

Adding that last line does throw an error though, because it's trying to read something from something that does not exists.

How to solve this ?

Simple add optional chaining in the mix:

```
{testObject.data?.[1].tcFunctions[0].tfName}
```

that `?.` basically says "do the rest only if *data* exists" so it will shortcut initially and not give any errors!

Comment: That worked - thank you so much! I can't believe 2 characters solved what I struggled for so long!